# need help in finding javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing this problem. i am getting strings like this.

```
'=--satya','=---satya1','=-----satya2'.
```

now my problem is i have to remove these special characters and print the strings like this

```
'satya'
'satya1'
'satya2'
```

please help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var s = '=---satya1';
s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

to replace all non-letter and non-number characters or

```
s.replace(/[-=]/g, '');
```

to remove all `-` and `=` characters or even

```
'=---satya-1=test'.replace(/(=\-+)/g, ''); // out: "satya-1=test"
```

to prevent removing further `-` or `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract that information with a regular expression such as

```
/\'\=-{0,}(satya[0-9]{0,})\'/
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/LFZje/

The regex matches

Literal `'`
Literal `=`
Zero or more `-`
Starts a capture group and captures
 - Literal `satya`
 - Zero or more `numbers`
Ends the capture group
Literal `'`

Then using code such as

```
var regex = /\'\=-{0,}(satya[0-9]{0,})\'/g;
while( (match = regex.exec("'=--satya','=---satya1','=-----satya2'")) !== null)
{
    // here match[0] is the entire capture
    // and match[1] is tthe content of the capture group, ie "satya1" or "satya2"
}
```

See the live example more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript function [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) which helps you to use regex for this case

```
var string = '=---satya1';
string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

Comment: something like this:
        str.replace(/(=|-)*/, "")